# jQuery Datatable Responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, datatables

I have a need to have a responsive table and allow it to have an x and y scroll.

Sadly no matter what I try I can not get it to work.

```
window.test = $('#tblSearchResults').DataTable( {
    responsive: true, 
    "scrollX": true, 
    "scrollY": "60vh", 
    "paging":   false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info":     false, 
    "filter": false, 
    "scrollCollapse": true, 
});
```

For a demo please see https://jsfiddle.net/5ybqqcv2/

[image]

Comment: i see a scoll bar....

Comment: @Rickert is that the JSFiddle scroll or on the table?  Is it the horizontal scroll?

Comment: i see both, the js fiddle scrollbar but also a table scrollbar

Comment: @Rickert it should show both horizontal and vertical scrollbars, plus the headers don't align with the table contents either.  I've added a screenshot to explain

Comment: i see on both sides of the fable scrollbars

Comment: @Ricket strange, I don't get the scrollbar in firefox!

Comment: I use chrome and there it works fine

Answer (score 0):

add a `max-width` to this class: `dataTables_scrollBody` that would fix it

Comment: sadly this doesn't cure the issue.

Comment: and if you add also a max-width or a with to the .row?